# using async with javascript forEach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an array of emails

```
emails.forEach(email => sendEmail(email)); --> 1

function2();
```

sendEmail is an asynchronous function
I want function2 to be invoked only after line 1 gets completed

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Promise.all(emails.map(email => sendEmail|(email)).then(() => { function2() });`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this?

Don't use `forEach`. Either use a normal for loop, and `await` each call, or if you want to run them in parallel use `map` and `await Promise.all`.

My preference would be:

```
async function sendAllEmails(emails) {
    await Promise.all(emails.map(email => sendEmail(email)));
    function2();
}
```